# innerHTML is not working in jquery

Tags: jquery

i've got nodes collection `$('.text-block')`. And i need to insert some html in it. doing like this

```
$('.text-block')[0].html('example text')
```

or

```
$('.text-block').get(0).html('example text')
```

and i've got an error

> html is not a function

What's wrong with this jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both the [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) method and `[]` (index) return DOM object, so you can't use jQuery methods on it. Use the [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method to get a jQuery object based on an index, or update the [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property of DOM object:

```
$('.text-block').eq(0).html('example text') 
// or
$('.text-block')[0].innerHTML = 'example text';
```

```js
$('.text-block').eq(0).html('example text 1')
$('.text-block')[1].innerHTML = 'example text 2';
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="text-block"></div>
  <div class="text-block"></div>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks for a minus bros. and appreciate answer. Just need to adapt that jquery needs to work with its own objects

Answer (score 1):

You can use first keyword with the class name to change its inner html

```
$('.text-block:first').html('example text');
```